# Remote Server Gives Oracle Not a Valid Month Error

Tags: c#, database, oracle

I have interesting error. This error happens only in remote server, my function works properly in my local computer.

here is my code;

```
        public bool GecisKontrol(KisiModel km)
    {
        bool varmi = false;
        //today without hours and minutes
        string bugun = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
                 + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.x)(PORT=1521))"
                 + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxxxxx)));"
                 + "User Id=xxxxxx;Password=xxxx;";
            con.Open();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                if (km.GECISDURUM == 0)
                {
                    //Normaly, i store variable ZAMAN as dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm
                    //But i need to compare as date, because of this i used TRUNC(ZAMAN)
                    cmd.CommandText = "select * from YENI_OTOMASYON_GECISLER WHERE TCKIMLIK = :1 and YEMEKHANEID = :2 and OGUNID = :3 and TRUNC(ZAMAN) = :4 and GECISDURUM = :5";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("1",
                   OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                   km.TCKimlik,
                   ParameterDirection.Input));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("2",
                   OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                   YemekHaneID,
                   ParameterDirection.Input));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("3",
                   OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                   OGUNID,
                   ParameterDirection.Input));
                   //I am sure, problem is here...
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("4",
                   OracleDbType.Date,
                   Convert.ToDateTime(bugun),
                   ParameterDirection.Input));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("5",
                   OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                   km.GECISDURUM,
                   ParameterDirection.Input));
                }



                using (OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        varmi = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        varmi = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return varmi;
    }
```

When i run this code in my local computer, i never get an error. **It gives error only in remote server.** I don't have enough information about remote server. That server admin don't share information. By the way, The column that name "ZAMAN" is DATE.

Comment: you are formatting and then parsing a date; when you format it, you specify a specific format, but when you parse it: you don't - that sounds like a likely problem spot, but... can't you just pass `DateTime.Now` as the value, rather than *any* formatting / parsing? i.e. `cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("4", OracleDbType.Date, DateTime.Now, ParameterDirection.Input));` (this sounds like a classic i18n/l10n problem)

Comment: But if i use DateTime.now the value will be like 2/24/2020 23:04... And i never get right comparasion. I need only date like 2/24/2020 not more...

Comment: Then use `DateTime.Today` ?

Answer (score 2):

Strip the time off your c# datetime but keep it as a date. By making `bugun` a string and pushing it into a date type sql parameter you're forcing oracle to parse your string back to a date, and it's failing because the server uses a different locale to your machine

```
DateTime bugun = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Comment: or `DateTime.Today`